# How to get all rows from left table in a join statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join, left-join

I have two tables. One is `Employee_Mstr` and other is `EmployeeLeaveRequest_mstr`.

My data:

[image: My data]

Comment: let us know what did you get, pick the answers please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT tab1.emp_cd, tab1.emp_name, SUM(tab2.num_dy)
FROM Employee_Mstr tab1, "2nd Table Records" tab2
where tab1.emp_cd = tab2.emp_cd
group by tab1.emp_cd, tab1.emp_name;
```

Should work, just set the correct table name for the 2nd table.

Comment: I tried this but this is giving me only Emp_cd "3" records but not 1 and 2 as I need all records from left table.

Comment: I updated the solution, with run results on MS SQL. At least it worked fine for me as you can see.

Comment: @CsabaBenko, why are you editing someone else's answer when you have your own answer to this question?!

Comment: If you need all results from the left table we need a left join.

SELECT tab1.emp_cd, tab1.emp_name, SUM(tab2.num_dy)
FROM Employee_Mstr tab1 
LEFT JOIN "2nd Table Records" tab2 ON tab1.emp_cd = tab2.emp_cd
group by tab1.emp_cd, tab1.emp_name;

Answer (score 3):

Use `GROUP BY`.

```
select t1.emp_cd, t1.emp_name, sum(t2.num_dy) from 
  Employee_Mstr t1 left join 
  EmployeeLeaveRequest_mstr t2 on t1.emp_cd = t2.emp_cd group by t1.emp_cd, t2.emp_name;
```

Comment: I tried this but this is giving me only Emp_cd 3 records but not 1 and 2 as I need all from left table.

Comment: Even this one is also working but I cant mark your answer as only one we can mark as answer... Thanks for your response...

Answer (score 0):

Make `pk emp_cd` the primary key, and then join the tales using `left join`.
You can then use `sumof` to add values, use `groupby` before adding the values.

If you want, just check w3school.com.

Answer (score 0):

```
select mstr.Emp_cd, mstr.Emp_Name, isnull(sum(det.num_dy), 0) as num_day
from dbo.Employee_Mstr mstr
left join dbo.Employee_Nums det on (mstr.Emp_cd = det.Emp_cd)
group by mstr.Emp_cd, mstr.Emp_Name;
```

should do the job.

Here it's results of SQL execution:

```
Emp_cd      Emp_Name
----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           A
2           B
3           C

(3 row(s) affected)

Emp_cd      num_dy
----------- -----------
3           4
3           2

(2 row(s) affected)

Emp_cd      Emp_Name                                           num_day
----------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
1           A                                                  0
2           B                                                  0
3           C                                                  6
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t1.cd, t1.name, sum(t2.num_dy) from employee_Mstr t1 
left join EmployeeLeaveRequest_mstr t2 on t1.cd = t2.cd group by t1.cd, t1.name;
```